# Single login, multiple application authentication

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication, single-sign-on

Is there a Codeigniter authentication server that's available for use? Trying to get a multi-application service going similar to Basecamp and I don't want to reinvent the wheel. Alternatively, are there any respectable resources that deal with this kind of authentication?

Thanks!

Comment: It might help to point out that "this kind of authentication" is often called "single sign on" (SSO). Using that term may help you find more info on the topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to create a user db, and authentication library to do the job.

[TankAuth](http://www.konyukhov.com/soft/tank_auth/) maybe?

You can have 2 applications either seperately installed, or sharing a CI installation using the same library and authentication database. I'd keep everything else application specific, just share profile and login information.

Answer (score 2):

Or, you can implement an OpenID service and have all of your CI applications connect via openid. This is the way StackOverflow does it. I'd google "codeigniter openid" to see what's available. here's a sampling:

http://thinkmoult.com/2009/02/22/use-codeigniter-openid-library-to-integrate-openid/

http://codeigniter.com/wiki/OpenID

Comment: I want to steer away from third-party authentication schemes for the time being. Thanks for your contribution - it'll definitely be something I'll be looking into for the future.

Comment: Well, then I'd say that @David Houde's answer would work for you. You can have multiple CI applications sharing the same library and database for user authentication. If you save session information in the database, then that could be passed to each application for single sign on capabilities.

Comment: +1 for mentioning OpenId. Everyone has hand-rolled their own SSO system but OpenId strives to make one, standardized way of authenticating users to lots of sites using a single username/password combination. It may not be what the OP is looking for but I suggest anyone who wants to take SSO seriously, try out OpenID! it is is relatively easy to implement too!

Answer (score 1):

[Facebook connect](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/#login) offers good authentication possibilities. Also [Google](http://code.google.com/intl/sv-SE/apis/accounts/docs/AuthForWebApps.html), [Yahoo!](http://developer.yahoo.com/auth/) and many other big sites offers similar posibilities.

If you mean that you want some form of 'register at one site get them all'-service, all you need to do is point the authentication to the same database on all sites.

Another posibility is making an authentication page then using [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) or [AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp) to check authentication.

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of the second paragraph. The third idea you have is a good one too! Thanks, Adam!